# Pass width and height as parameters to CSS selector

Tags: parameters, css-selectors

I've a few .containers CSS selectors which wraps around input boxes which have the same attributes except for the width and height. Is it possible to pass the width and height when I define **class="container"** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but you want to send back the width and height of the container class so that elements with that class later on inherit that width and height?

Not with pure CSS. It's called cascading style sheets, because you can't go in reverse, if that makes sense.

It's easy with JavaScript, though. In jQuery, for example, you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $('.container:first').css('width');
    var height = $('.container:first').css('height');
    $('.container').css({'width': width, 'height': height});
});
```

Comment: Thanks soren121, I've seem some where they implement by calling the class name like "width340". So basically it calls 2 classes like class="container width340". Then in CSS it would be '.width340 { width: 340px; } . Do you reckon it is good practice?

Comment: Depends on how much you intend on using the class. If it's once or twice, I would go with a style attribute. More than that, a class would be okay. I had assumed you didn't know the width and height, because of browser behavior or a dynamic script out of your control.